# Angular 2 ReactiveForms: user input though a pipe before updating the model?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

With ReactiveForms is it possible to run user input though a Pipe before updating the model?

I want to covert the user input (Kilobytes, Megabytes, etc) to a standard unit (bytes) before it's sent to the database, and I want the reverse to happen when viewing the saved data.

I have already written the transformations, but I am a little lost on how to implement this into my form.

In a template it would look something like this:
`{{ user_input | human_to_bytes }}`

Comment: I can see 2 options for this: use `(change)` in your `inputs` and modify the value of `control` or create a *general* directive.